BUN: symbol 'napi_register_module_v1' not found in native module. Is this a Node API (napi) module?
I'm using Bun v1.1.18 with using bun --hot with a big express project transpiled using swc to a commonjs type which works just fine with nodejs but seems to have a little bit problem with Bun. the error is related to bcrypt:
TypeError: symbol 'napi_register_module_v1' not found in native module. Is this a Node API (napi) module?
 at ...

6 | var bindings = require(binding_path);
                           ^


the transpiled swc code of commonjs is:
const _bcrypt = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("bcrypt"));

typescript code:
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

how can I solve this? is there an option where I'm able to use this bcrypt module in bun? I know I should open up an issue for this but its since version v0.0.83 till now and I'm wondering if is there a solution for this?
